# How to solve java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: Could not read resultset: Connection reset?

Tags: java, mysql, sql, exception, mariadb

I am getting an exception when calling database code after a period of inactivity

```
java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: Could not read resultset: Connection reset
        at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.SQLExceptionMapper.get(SQLExceptionMapper.java:136)
        at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.SQLExceptionMapper.throwException(SQLExceptionMapper.java:106)
        at org.mariadb.jdbc.MySQLStatement.executeQueryEpilog(MySQLStatement.java:264)
        at org.mariadb.jdbc.MySQLStatement.execute(MySQLStatement.java:288)
        at org.mariadb.jdbc.MySQLStatement.executeQuery(MySQLStatement.java:302)
        at org.mariadb.jdbc.MySQLStatement.executeQuery(MySQLStatement.java:361)
        at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingStatement.executeQuery(DelegatingStatement.java:208)
        at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingStatement.executeQuery(DelegatingStatement.java:208)
        at com.vimba.database.DBFactory.attemptLoginWithTempPasswordDetails(DBFactory.java:181)
        at com.vimba.database.DBFactory.authenticate(DBFactory.java:131)
        at com.vimba.service.ExposedFunctions.login(ExposedFunctions.java:88)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.api.server.InstanceResolver$1.invoke(InstanceResolver.java:210)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.server.InvokerTube$2.invoke(InvokerTube.java:132)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.server.sei.EndpointMethodHandler.invoke(EndpointMethodHandler.java:241)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.server.sei.SEIInvokerTube.processRequest(SEIInvokerTube.java:74)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.__doRun(Fiber.java:559)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber._doRun(Fiber.java:518)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.doRun(Fiber.java:503)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.runSync(Fiber.java:400)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.server.WSEndpointImpl$2.process(WSEndpointImpl.java:226)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter$HttpToolkit.handle(HttpAdapter.java:375)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter.handle(HttpAdapter.java:175)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.ServletAdapter.handle(ServletAdapter.java:134)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServletDelegate.doPost(WSServletDelegate.java:159)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServlet.doPost(WSServlet.java:49)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:754)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:295)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:230)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:149)
        at org.jboss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityContextAssociationValve.java:169)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:145)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:97)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:102)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:336)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:856)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:653)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:920)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.common.QueryException: Could not read resultset: Connection reset
        at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.mysql.MySQLProtocol.getResult(MySQLProtocol.java:926)
        at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.mysql.MySQLProtocol.executeQuery(MySQLProtocol.java:991)
        at org.mariadb.jdbc.MySQLStatement.execute(MySQLStatement.java:281)
        ... 40 more
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
```

I have tried to change the /etc/my.cnf to add a wait_timeout of a week but it has not made a difference;

```
[mysqld]
datadir=/var/lib/mysql
socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
# Disabling symbolic-links is recommended to prevent assorted security risks
symbolic-links=0
# Settings user and group are ignored when systemd is used.
# If you need to run mysqld under a different user or group,
# customize your systemd unit file for mysqld/mariadb according to the
# instructions in http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Systemd

# Currently, there are mariadb and community-mysql packages in Fedora.
# This particular config file is included in respective RPMs of both of them,
# so the following settings are general and will be also used by both of them.
# Otherwise the RPMs would be in conflict.
# Settings for particular implementations like MariaDB are then
# defined in appropriate sections; for MariaDB server in [mariadb] section in
# /etc/my.cnf.d/server.cnf (part of mariadb-server).
# It doesn't matter that we set these settings only for [mysqld] here,
# because they will be read and used in mysqld_safe as well.
log-error=/var/log/mysqld.log
pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid

[mysqld_safe]

#
# include all files from the config directory
#
!includedir /etc/my.cnf.d

#one week timeout to see if exception goes
wait_timeout=604800

event_scheduler=on
/etc/my.cnf (END)
```

Does anyone know how to solve this issue?

Comment: The exception is saying that your connection is closed when you're trying to read your ResultSet, are you working with threads ?
ps : the ping is not helping because you're opening another connection ...

Comment: does conn = source.getConnection(); not get me a new connection?

Comment: can you share the code that calling to db?
and what operation you doing ? insert/updating? Perhaps is locking issues ?

Comment: It is indeed, but the connection used for your statement is different ! So keeping alive another connection is not useful ... What is your wait_timeout value in mariadb ? Is your query processing long ? Maybe a network error closing the connection ...

Comment: will add some examples of where it fails now to the question

Comment: If you swallow up exceptions, how do you even know that your ping is working?

Comment: i deleted my log to save room

Comment: If you're using a PreparedStatement you do not need to pass argument when you're executing ... Not the problem but still searching :)

Comment: Im guessing you couldn't find a solution?

Comment: try setting also the interactive_timeout value, depending on which client you use. wait_timeout is only taken into account on tcp based connections - not if youre using e.g. sockets or named pipes as stated in your conf, see [mysql](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/de/server-system-variables.html)

Comment: I am getting java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException when mysqld got signal 6. Then I change some values for parameters as there is a suggestion in a message. Or then I restart.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in the end i gave up and just wrote a method to ping the database every hour

```
public static void pingServer(final BasicDataSource source){
    final Thread serverPing = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Connection conn = null;
            try {
                while(!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()){
                    String sql = "/* ping */ SELECT 1";
                    PreparedStatement st = null;
                    conn = source.getConnection();
                    st = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
                    st.executeUpdate(sql);
                    LOGGER.info("Database connection test successful");
                    DatabaseUtilities.closeConnection(conn);
                    TimeUnit.HOURS.sleep(1);
                }
            } catch (SQLException | InterruptedException e) {
                LOGGER.error("Unable to continue pinging database server", e);
                DatabaseUtilities.closeConnection(conn);
            }
            finally{
                DatabaseUtilities.closeConnection(conn);
            }
        }
    });
    serverPing.setDaemon(true);
    serverPing.start();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can configure [DBCP](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-dbcp/configuration.html) to do that connection check for you. Add something like this to your config

```
validationQuery="/* ping */ SELECT 1"
testOnBorrow="true"
```

DBCP will check if the connection is alive every time you get a connection from the pool, dropping dead connections and creating new ones when needed

Comment: but why would a connection be dead that is in the pool?

Comment: sorry to hear that @Biscuit128

Answer (score 0):

Change String jdbcUrl

**From:** String jdbcUrl = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/web_customer_tracker?useSSL=false";

**To:** String jdbcUrl = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/web_customer_tracker?useSSL=false&allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true";

For **Maven** file

Step 1) Open folder src/main/resources

Step 2) Open persistence-mysql.properties

Step 3) Change jdbc.url

from

```
jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/web_customer_tracker?useSSL=false
```

to

```
jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/web_customer_tracker?useSSL=false&allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true
```